# deleting nodes from linked list, which are divisible by 2

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Want to add a function in my List class to delete nodes which are divisible by 2.

The `if` part is working, but in `else` case isn't working.

```
void List::ClearDv() {

   if(GetLength()>=1 && m_first->info%2==0) {
      DeleteAt(0);
      return;
   } 
   else{
      Node*T=m_first;
      while(T!=NULL)
      {
         T=T->link;
         if(T->info%2==0){
            Node* P=T;
            T=T->link;
            delete P;

         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you intend your `then` part to trigger when `GetLength()==1`, and the root is divisible by 2? Currently your `else` will trigger only when `GetLength () < 1` or root is **not** divisible by 2.

Comment: @David Tsaturyan  It is not clear why in the if statement you call function DeleteAt and in the else statement you delete a node manually. You should show how the list is defined.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Why my `else` will trigger when `GetLength()<1` ? if my `GetLength()>1` , but `m_first->info%2!=0` in that case what will happen?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I can call the `DeleteAt()` function in `else' field too, but wanted to write manually. Think in `List` statement all are okay, cause the other functions working clearly.

Comment: @DavidTsaturyan Refer to the magical word: **or**, which is located right after "`GetLength () < 1`". On the other note, I just understood what meant by "node", you meant "node with it's sub-tree". That's why I didn't answer, but commented instead, since I didn't understand if that was intentional, or mistype. Please define what do you mean by "else case isn't working". It isn't very descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the original special case of the first node was unsound, but also needing a special case of the first node is poor style for a linked list.  Using a pointer to pointer `Node**` is a better solution to the general problem that the first node is owned differently than all later nodes:

```
void List::ClearDv() {
   Node** p = &m_first;
   while ( *p )
   {
      Node* t=*p;
      if ( t->info % 2 )
      {
         p = &(t->link);  // Advance to next Node
      }
      else
      {
         *p = t->link;  // Unlink Node t
         delete t;   // Then delete it.
      }
   }
}
```

Notice the key operation `% 2` occurs in just one place in the code.  There is no need for a special case based on original size.  There is no need for a different way of unlinking the first Node vs. any other Node.  The code is generally more testable and maintainable because each operation is done in a minimum of places.

Answer (score 0):

In general I see two issues in `else` branch:

1. You don't re-link next node to keep linked list linked.
2. When this happens:

   ```
       Node* P=T;
       T=T->link;
   ```

   On the next iteration node will be skipped because of the `T=T->link;` in the beginning of the cycle.